# Where my files exist in Docker image?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, docker, travis-ci, dockerfile

I'll switch to container based infrastructure in my Travis-CI builds. So
I wrote following commands in my Dockerfile, image was successfully built:

```
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install gcc-4.9 -y
RUN apt-get install build-essential perl python git -y
RUN apt-get install "^libxcb.*" libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libedit-dev -y
RUN apt-get install flex bison gperf libicu-dev libxslt-dev -y

RUN git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git qt5
RUN cd qt5 && perl init-repository

RUN unset QTDIR
RUN export PATH="$PWD/qtbase/bin:$PWD/qtrepotools/bin:$PATH"
RUN cd qt5 && ./configure -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests
RUN cd qt5 && make
RUN cd qt5 && make install

RUN git clone git://code.qt.io/qt-creator/qt-creator.git qt-creator
RUN mkdir qt-creator-build
RUN cd qt-creator-build
RUN ../qt5/qtbase/bin/qmake -r ../qt-creator/qtcreator.pro
RUN make -j5
```

Before I push it to Docker Hub I need to know where is my stuff was created in the image. I need something like map of my files for getting access from Travis-CI. Please help me to understand. Thanks

UPD: actually, I need only an absolute path of `qt-creator-build` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your commands, the absolute path to the `qt-creator-build` folder should be `/qt-creator-build`, as the root directory `/` is the default working directory for **every** docker command.

That said, the command `RUN make -j5` should probably be `RUN cd qt-creator-build && make -j5`, but **only** if you actually want to run `make -j5` **inside** `qt-creator-build`, and that's what I understood from your code.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir) of Docker, you can use the [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) command to change de working directory, like:

```
WORKDIR qt-creator-build
```